# How to analyze multiple logfiles

Tags: php, parsing

I have a folder called `awstats` which contains all the log files for each month, I need to parse all of them and get content for all the files at the `same time`

I tried this :

```
$filename = DOCUMENT_ROOT."sites/".HOSTNAME."/awstats/".$_SESSION['awstat_month'].$_SESSION['awstat_year']."."HOSTNAME".txt";
if(file_exists($filename))
    $awstats = file_get_contents($filename) ; 
else {
    print_warning("the log file does not exist!");
    return;
}
```

But it only parse a log file at the time. Is there a way to parse all the log file at the same time and get a certain content for each file? 
Much Appreciated!

Comment: Does the folder `awstats` contain anything besides the log files? And do you want to parse all of them for all time, or just parse a certain date range?

Comment: No it only contains logfiles `032014.test.txt` & `022014.test.txt` and so on ..

Comment: i need to parse them all at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function :

```
<?php

foreach (glob(DOCUMENT_ROOT."sites/".HOSTNAME."/awstats/*.txt") as $filename) {

    $awstats = file_get_contents($filename) ;
    // do what you want with the content

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should in some way iterate over those statistic files.
It seems those variable parameters are @ $_SESSION['awstat_mont'] and $_SESSION['awstat_year']
so a naive solution would be a double foreach loop:
(I am assuming you are using php so have a look over here: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($allYearsToCheck as $year) {
   foreach ($allMonthToCheck as $month) {
      $filename =DOCUMENT_ROOT."sites/".HOSTNAME."/awstats/".$month.$year."."HOSTNAME".txt";
      if(file_exists($filename)){
         $awstats .= file_get_contents($filename) ; 
      }
      else {
         print_warning("the log file does not exist!"
      }
   }
}
```

where allMontToCheck and allYearsToCheck are arrays containig all years and month you would like to check.
$awstats will contain all logfiles concatenated.